# How to access a variable inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have the following JSON output and I need to access the variable `TN_TEXTO`. How can I access it?

```
["data", [
    ["notification",
    {
        "TN_CODIGO": "3",
        "TN_TP_CODIGO": "1",
        "TN_TEXTO": "dddddddddddd",
        "TN_DATA": "1325708743",
        "TN_LINK": "",
        "TN_READ": "0"
    }]
]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's kind of a weird format.

Comment: my php generates this... two arrays nested

Comment: Can you change how your php generates it and use nested objects instead?

Comment: can you give me a hint on it? i don't know how! thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert a string to an object. Then you can use JavaScript syntax on it.

```
var object = JSON.parse(string);
alert(obj[1][0][1].TN_TEXTO);
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qFks2/)

Comment: it gives me this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d

This is shown on error console on Chromium browser

Comment: @user1130879 I was missing an array but I think your problem lies in how you're parsing it. Check my post, I added an example.

Comment: yep... it's working nice on your example... i'll try harder then!

Answer (score 0):

```
myvar = ["data", [
    ["notification",
    {
        "TN_CODIGO": "3",
        "TN_TP_CODIGO": "1",
        "TN_TEXTO": "dddddddddddd",
        "TN_DATA": "1325708743",
        "TN_LINK": "",
        "TN_READ": "0"
    }]
]]


alert(myvar[1][1]["TN_CODIGO"]); // is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSON string:

```
var json = '["data", [["notification", { "TN_CODIGO": "3", "TN_TP_CODIGO": "1", "TN_TEXTO": "dddddddddddd", "TN_DATA": "1325708743", "TN_LINK": "", "TN_READ": "0" }] ]]';
var array = JSON.parse(json);
alert(array[1][0][1]["TN_TEXTO"]);
```

If you have already parsed the string just:

```
alert(array[1][0][1]["TN_TEXTO"]);
```